# Theorems Supporting the Monte Carlo Method

Tags: probability, statistics, monte-carlo, sampling-theory

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables and $Y=g(X)$.  I then drawn $n$ random samples X to get the set $\{x_1, x_2, ..., x_n\}$ according to the CDF of $X$ called $F_X(x)$.  I process each sample as $y_i=g(x_i) \forall i \in \{1,2,...,n\}$ to get $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$.

My question is this: how do I know that $\{y_1, y_2, ..., y_n\}$ is a random sample of $Y$ according to the CDF of $Y$ called $F_Y(y)$?  Is there a theorem that proves this property?  This appears to be a fundamental assumption of the Monte Carlo method, but I'm struggling to find it explicitly identified anywhere.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'according to $F_Y$' and 'according to the CDF of X called $F_X$'?

Comment: @Alborz I think Joey is saying that suppose we can sample from a distribution $F_X$. We then apply $g$ on our sample. Does it follow that this is a sample from $F_{g(X)}$?

Comment: First note that the $Y_i$ are independent of each other if the $X_i$ are (functions of independent random variables are independent), so you can take $n=1$.  Then (assuming $g$ is a measurable function) go back to the original definition of a random variable as a measurable function from the sample space to a state space, and then note this makes $g(X)$ a function of a function and so itself a function with the desired properties

Comment: @AndrewZhang You are correct.  By $F_Y$ I was intending to indicate the CDF of $Y$.  This is equivalent to saying the CDF $F_{g(X)}$.  I have clarified this in my question.  And by saying "sampled according to ..." you can think of this as Inverse Transform Sampling.  i.e. the samples $x_i$ are distributed uniformly on $F^{-1}_X$.

Comment: This has nothing to do specifically with the Monte Carlo method. If you correctly sample from the distribution of $X$ and $Y=g(X)$, then applying $g$ to the samples by definition yields a correct sample from $Y$, no matter how you got the correct sample of $X$.